# jQuery Datatables fnReloadAjax works but generates an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I am using the following code to reload the data in a jQuery datatable.

```
$(".unread-rows").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    message_table.fnReloadAjax("/letters/ajax/inbox/1");
    message_table.fnDraw();
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

It reloads the data fine but it also causes an alert to appear saying:

`DataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.`

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: `fnReloadAjax` is a plug-in API function (http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api). You cannot use it in context of datatable object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring any bugs in the `fnRelaodAjax` function :

1. Have you checked if your server returns valid json data ?
2. Have you checked if it returns an object with the following structure : `{aaData: [...]}`, or a structure that matches your `sAjaxDataProp` property ? (look for "sAjaxSource" and "sAjaxDataProp" in the [doc page](http://datatables.net/usage/options))